# How to have an optional static block inside a dynamic block

Tags: terraform

In my base module I have this:

```
 dynamic "settings" {
    for_each = var.settings
    content {
      type           = settings.value["type"]
      operator       = settings.value["operator"]
      property       = settings.value["property"]
      target         = settings.value["target"]
      path = settings.value["path"]
    }
  }
```

`path` is a conditional field sometimes present sometimes not and is actually a block. In the calling module:

```
  settings = [
    { "operator" = "lessThan", "type" = "responseTime", "target" = 10000 },
    { "operator" = "is", "type" = "statusCode", "target" = 200 },
    { "operator" = "is", "property" = "allow", "type" = "header", "target" = "true" },
    { "operator" = "validate", "type" = "body", "path" = { "operator" = "contains", "targetValue" = "9754389", "jsonPath" = "141234" } }
  ]
```

Now when I try to plan this I get following error:

> An argument named "path" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "path"?

Question is, how can I define a block field inside a dynamic block?

I tried using a nested dynamic block and working with for-each but `path` can only have *one instance*, so it gives error that can't have more than one instance.

Comment: What is the context of `settings`? Can you provide full code of a resource where you use it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't created a block inside a `dynamic` block before, so I'm just guessing here. Have you tried something like this:

```
dynamic "settings" {
  for_each = var.settings
  content {
    type           = settings.value["type"]
    operator       = settings.value["operator"]
    property       = settings.value["property"]
    target         = settings.value["target"]
    path {
      operator    = settings.value["path"]["operator"]
      targetValue = settings.value["path"]["targetValue"]
      jsonPath    = settings.value["path"]["jsonPath"]
    }
  }
}
```

As written, that will require that `"path"` exists in all of your `settings` entries, but if that works you might be able to fiddle around with some other approach to make it optional.

Just a next-step suggestion, I'm interested to know how you get on.

Comment: Since its an optional element it throws an error `The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

Comment: Since what's an optional element?

Comment: as stated in question _path is a conditional field sometimes present sometimes not and is actually a block._

Comment: Right, and like I said in the answer, this is just a partial suggestion that might hey you a step closer to what you want, but not all the way (or it might not, of course). Does this at least work for the case where `path` is present?